# Call function automatically whenever I open a Dialog

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I've got some code in my `CMyView` class. There I open a dialog with `DoModal()`:

```
AnotherDialog dlg;
dlg.DoModal();
```

Now I want to automatically run a function. The poblem is, whenever I call `dlg.DoModal()`, the compiler waits till I close the Dialog window again, to continue running my code into the `CMyView` class. The function can also automatically be called into my `AnotherDialog` class. 
Can anyone tell me, how I can automatically run a function whenever I open another Dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AnotherDialog` has a constructor, `AnotherDialog::AnotherDialog()`. Any function called from there will be called every time a dialog is created *without providing arguments*. If you add constructor overloads, each constructor can have different behavior, and it's up to you to make your code not confusing. (I.e. just be consistent)

If `AnotherDialog` is not your class, you may want to derive from it instead: `class MyOtherDialog : public AnotherDialog`. You can now have a `MyOtherDialog::MyOtherDialog` constructor which is called after `AnotherDialog::AnotherDialog()`.

You could also add code to `DoModal()`, again in the existing class or a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your view class is waiting because you are using the DoModal () method.  By definition, DoModal is synchronous so it will wait for the dialog to close before continuing.  Without knowing too much about your design, I would guess that you should use a "modeless" dialog invocation instead.